# uploading photo using windows form in c# and make processing on it then show the result photo

Tags: c#

I don't know how to upload an image and make processing on it then show the result image. If any one can help me?

Here what i have done:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Title = "open image";
            ofd.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("test");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Where you want to upload image? SqlDatabase or HttpServer

Answer (score 0):

This is an example code to upload an image file to a ftp server. You can use something like this function.

```
public void upload_image_file() 
{ 
  using (WebClient client = new WebClient())  
  { client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "p/w"); 

    client.UploadFile("FTP_PATH/YOUR FILE NAME.extention", "STOR", "where the local file stored/YOUR FILE NAME.extention"); 
  } 
}
```